# Top navigation drop-down trouble

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

this is going to be embarrassing, but I haven't been writing code/css for a while, so please bear with me ;-)

All I need is a simple drop down menu, but for some reason the one I came up with does not work, the drop down disappears when moving the mouse down, and text (from my main content) gets overlayed. I suspect this is happening because I use absolute position for my elements, but there must be a solution other than moving content down by stating #main top: 300px;

http://dynomotion.com/dev/home/About.html

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

Your `#main` div is covering up the `#menu` div which blocks the functionality you are seeking. You can solve this by adjusting your `#menu` statement in `style.css` to include a z-index.

For example:

```
#menu { 
    position:absolute; 
    left: 12px; 
    top: 80px; 
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot!